# CreateFileAsync UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, exception, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code that fetches a dynamic image from a webserver in my Windows 8 app.

```
        private async Task httpFetcher()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(
HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.reignofcomputer.com/imgdump/sample.png");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,
            HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        Uri imageUri;
        BitmapImage image = null;

            var imageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
         "sample.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var fs = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0));
            writer.WriteBytes(await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());
            await writer.StoreAsync();
            writer.DetachStream();
            await fs.FlushAsync();
            writer.Dispose();

            if (Uri.TryCreate(imageFile.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out imageUri))
            {
                image = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
            }

        image1.Source = image;
    }
```

This works most of the time, but for some reason there are times where I get an

> UnauthorizedAccessException (0x80070005, E_ACCESSDENIED), HResult
>   -2147024891.

Because the errors are random and it usually works, I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe, file with the same name already exists `CreateFileAsync` is trying to replace existing file but it is locked by another process.

Comment: Hmm, any idea how I can check for this and if so, how I can make the app wait until the file is unlocked before continuing?

Comment: You can create situation described in my comment yourself. `how I can make the app wait until the file is unlocked before continuing?` It's not a good idea. You never know what another process is doing. It might take hours for this process to _unlock_ file.

Comment: Hmm, the only process that should have access to this file is the app itself, since it's storing the file in the app's LocalFolder which shouldn't be touched by the user. Regardless, any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Maybe your another thread is locking file. Does this exception happens when image is opened in your application and you receive another file?

Comment: Once the image is downloaded the image is shown on screen. When the user tries to get another image (refresh) I set the image source to null first, so I don't see why the image would still be in use.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue recently, after some test I find that it's because some programs may be deleting the file while you try to access it. 
Here's how I did the test.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(Create);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(Delete);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

    }


    private static void Create()
    {

        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.IO.TextWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("file.txt");
                i++;
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine(i);
                writer.Write(i);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Boom at: " + i.ToString());
        }


    }

    private static void Delete()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                System.IO.File.Delete("file.txt");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }

    }
```